# Getting value from an array in powershell

Tags: arrays

I'm writing a script that reads a `CSV` file, it does everything I want it to do, but how would get the value of `CoreID`, which is `FMD354800203` from the array below?

```
@{Branch Number=8002; CoreID=FMD354800203; Available=Y; Workstation=}
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`

We can use this: `Wscript.Echo x(1)`

or

`$x[1]`

This will access the second item

so for you, try something like `$array[CoreID]`

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll try that

Comment: Just to make sure,   @{Branch Number=8002; CoreID=FMD354800203; Available=Y; Workstation=}   this is an array correct?

Comment: @TonyAntony you didn't specify the name of your array, what ever its name is : $name[CoreID]

Comment: you have type $name.GetType(); to check what it is.

Comment: -------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear, I'm really new to powershell

Comment: Would it be easier if I paste in my whole code here?

Comment: go head and post it

Comment: Apparently my code is too long, it won't let me post it

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'll do some more Googling